# Feedback Form to receive an email in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Actually in my application i have a feedback form to get the complaints through email. So how can i achieve to get an email from each users to some particular email ("abed@gmail.com"). 
   Usually, i use user account  credentials to send email to others.

**Code to send email**

```
     public ActionResult SendEmail(string SentTo, string Text)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("senderemail");
        msg.To.Add(SentTo);
        msg.Subject = "Password";
        msg.Body = Text;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        //client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailaddress", "password");
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result =  false;
        }

        return View();

    }
```

But how can i receive an email from contact form?
   Looking for some help to get the solution for my issue.  Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Just send from your email to yourself and add their supplied email address from the contact form to your `ReplyToList` like `msg.ReplyToList.Add(suppliedEmail);`

Comment: i am not looking to send an email. I am looking to receive an email from the email id supplied in contact form @lamelemon

Comment: You want the contact form to send you an email *from* their supplied email address?  That's exactly what I'm suggesting above, except you can't send it from *their* email address because you don't have the credentials.  You have to send it from your smtp client to yourself, hence receive from yourself.

Comment: Thanks @lamelemon it works